# QSocketNotifier signal has a different signature than the assigned slot

Tags: qt, signals-slots

How can the QSocketNotifier signal i.e. activated have a different signature than the assigned slot in the following code

```
connect(my_skt_read_notifier, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(skt_process_rcv()));
```

I had the impression that signals and slots should have the same signature, is that right?

what does the int parameter in the notifier indicate?

Comment: If the slot has fewer parameters then it's not a problem. But the existing parameters must be same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html):

> The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving
>   slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it
>   receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)...

So, in your case it should also work because the slot has less arguments than the connected signal.